# knitr to pdf inserts unwanted newpage

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown, knitr

I have found a strange behavior when knitting an Rmd document to PDF using Rstudio under the following circumstances:

- The document includes a *list*, and only the two last items are placed (after knitting to PDF) in the following page of the PDF.
- The list is followed by a table (in a separate paragraph).

When knitted to PDF, the PDF document shows:

- The page 1, which includes the longest part of the list.
- The page 2, which includes the last two items of the list. and a large empty space below.
- The page 3, which includes the table

If you modify by adding a new item to the list, things go better:

- page 1 shows the longest part of the list,
- page 2 shows the remainder of the list (3 items or more), plus the table just correctly below the list.

I include a MWE that I hope is reproducible (in spite of possible different settings of paper size, etc, in that case I pray you add/remove lines for getting the list truncated in one page and showing only two items in the next one, in order to reproduce the strange behavior).

I attach a screenshot of the PDF output[image: pdf-output]

```
---
title: "Title"
author: "Author"
date: "Date"
output: pdf_document
---

Paragraph

Paragraph

Paragraph

Paragraph

Paragraph

Paragraph

Paragraph

Paragraph

Paragraph

Paragraph

Paragraph

Paragraph

Paragraph

Paragraph

Paragraph

Paragraph

Paragraph

Paragraph

Paragraph

Paragraph

Paragraph

Paragraph

Paragraph

Paragraph

Paragraph

Paragraph

Paragraph

Paragraph

Paragraph

Paragraph

- List
- List
- List
- List

Table | hello
------|-----
Table | bye
```

Thanks for your attention!!!

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, even after removing a couple of paragraphs such that exactly two list items end up on page 2. Are you using current versions of R, RStudio and knitr?

Comment: Thanks for checking, @CL. I am using Rstudio (version 1.2.5019), R (version 3.6.1) and knitr (version 1.26)

Comment: Cannot reproduce the error either, using knitr version 1.27 and R version 3.6.2 - perhaps try to update?

Comment: I've seen differences between same-R, same-knitr, same TinyTeX on windows versus linux, so it does not surprise me. (I don't have ready artifacts, code, or proof, but it has happened. I need to verify if *that* problem still exists.)